# django - user_type of User in another model

Tags: django

I have a model like Community, where some users can be admins and other users are normal users. I can link user the community as foreignkey or someother possible relationship. But, how can I implement user_type ? Where should I have this field ? Is it just another field in the model Community ?

Comment: Please, post the code for your models.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want to provide different access levels to user in the community based on their user_type.

In that  case, you can either keep a FK from UserProfile to Commmunity(in case one user will only be part of one community).

If users can be part of various communites, you should keep a ManyToManyField called `users` on Community model.

After this just keep these user in groups (See Django group and Permission). Set permission on Groups you define. Based on what group a user in, he will have the group permission. Use these permission to decide what access to give to a particular user.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the size and other attributes of the data but a common way to go about it would be to have a one-to-many relationship between Community and User. Then you can have a field in User that states the user type.

In the database you will have a Community table and a User table which are linked via foreign key, and the User table will store the user type information.